# Issue with VBA file path concatenating

Tags: r, excel, vba, escaping, filepath

I have a R script that is executed by VBA. When I explicitly state the file path this executes as expected, however when I re-construct the file path using Application.ThisWorkbook.Path the script does not execute.

Using Debug.Print they are identical, so I'm abit confused what is the issue, perhaps with the escapes?

The file path that executes:

```
path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\RScript.exe"" ""C:\Users\ggeor\Desktop\Freelance Consulting\ABC Corp\Model\Final Models\Scripts\gmaps_distance_matrix_final_new.R"""
```

The concatenated file path that does not execute:

```
path1 = """C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\RScript.exe"" """
path2 = "" & Application.ThisWorkbook.path & "\Scripts\gmaps_distance_matrix_final_new.R"""
path = path1 & path2
```

Appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I was using a package in R, which required R Studio to be open. The original file path works.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `StrComp`. Moreover, could you try this:

```
path1 = chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\RScript.exe" & chr(34)
path2 = chr(34) & Application.ThisWorkbook.path & "\Scripts\gmaps_distance_matrix_final_new.R" & chr(34)
path = path1 & " " & path2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jakub, Actually figured out the issue, I was using a package in R which required R Studio to be open. My original file path works. Thankyou for your reply though